# VB.NET How do I add a return attribute?

Tags: vb.net, return-value, c#-to-vb.net

I am converting C# code to VB.Net and the C code has this above the function:

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Name", IsNullable=true)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this C# code:

```
public [return:XmlElement("Name", IsNullable=true)] string Foo()
{
    return "";
}
```

will translate to something like:

```
Public Function Foo() As <XmlElement("Name", IsNullable := True)> String
    Return ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

IN VB.Net simply put it just before the type in the As clause

```
Public Function Example() As <XmlElementAttribute("Name", IsNullable:=true)> As SomeType
  ...
End FUnction
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really worked much with VB, but for a subroutine, I think to need to put a variable which is the same name as the subroutine.

But since you say VB .NET, doesn't the regular 'Return' keyword do something?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx

If that is not the case, I'm not sure what exact problem you are facing. It's be helpful if you could provide more information.